# add one radio button into 2 groups

Tags: html-parsing

I know this is probably very elementary, but I can't seem to figure it out.
I need radio buttons that are mutually exclusive horizontally as well as vertically.
How can I assign a radio button to two groups?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? I think an alternative to this method can be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set GroupName property in RadioButton.

for example:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnOne" runat="server" Text="One" GroupName="Number" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnTwo" runat="server" Text="Two" GroupName="Number" />

<asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnMan" runat="server" Text="Man" GroupName="Sex" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnWoman" runat="server" Text="Woman" GroupName="Sex" />
```

or use RadioButtonList control

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtnListExample" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="TestOne" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="TestTwo" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="TestThree" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```